Can stainless steel construction screws be used with galvanized hurricane ties?
I have some stainless steel construction screws. Can they be used with galvanized hurricane ties in combination with pressure-treated/ground-contact dimensional lumber?

Stainless is generally approved for PT lumber, but the gauge, length, and strength of the fastener seems to be up to the manufacturer of the hurricane ties to approve. Is this fastener on their list of approved fasteners?

Are you concerned about galvanic corrosion or something else? Will this setup get wet (or even damp) for prolonged periods of time?

Yes, the metals interacting.  It is 6x6 pressure-treated/ground-contact wood beam "skid" foundation for a shed that is in an area with a high water table.  The topsoil has been cleared away to a depth of about six inches and filled with crushed stone.  The beams don't sit on the rock but are mounted in galvanized brackets on helical piles.  Resting atop the beams (anchored with straps) will be a 2x6 floor system (joists and headers), also PT/GC.  My concern is can I use SS screws with galvanized straps.  Or do I need to buy SS straps, which cost about 5x as much.
